# Set randomSeed to Webots World for correct reproducibility

Tags: webots

I'm trying to set the seed value for random number generator and as [mentioned in the documentation](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/worldinfo) that value must be set in the `randomSeed` field from the `WorldInfo` Node.

I know that using the `Supevisor` I can change the field values in any Node during runtime. Can this be done?
Or which is the correct way to set that value?

In Python I'm currently using this line of code to set a seed value.
`self.__robot.getFromDef('World').getField('randomSeed').setSFInt32(0 if seed is None else seed)`

Comment: Can you explain why do you need to change this random number generator programmatically? Can't you simply set the value of the seed in `WorldInfo.randomSeed` in the world file before launching Webots?

Comment: Only to control the seed value in a single place. For example, in a reinforcement learning experiment I am setting a seed value for the algorithm, the neural network and the environment. By changing this value, I can observe the generalization capacity by running the experiment many times with different values.

Comment: In that case, I would recommend that your script would simply modify the world file to change the seed value before launching Webots.